# Absolute Value (abs) of NSDecimalNumber without loss of precision

Tags: objective-c

I need to get the absolute value of an NSDecimalNumber without loss of precision. I can't seem to find a way to do this without converting to decimal or float (with a loss of precision). Is there a method to do this?

Comment: compare it to zero, if it's less, multiply it by -1, otherwise use it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the built-in functions of the NSDecimalNumber class to compare the number to zero, then multiply by -1 as appropriate. For example:

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)abs:(NSDecimalNumber *)num {
    if ([num compare:[NSDecimalNumber zero]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        // Number is negative. Multiply by -1
        NSDecimalNumber * negativeOne = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1
                                                                          exponent:0
                                                                        isNegative:YES];
        return [num decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:negativeOne];
    } else {
        return num;
    }
}
```

Since this method works solely with NSDecimalNumbers, there's no loss of precision.

Comment: I knew there had to be something simple I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

There is a minor error in the answer: negativeOne should be a pointer. Here is a revised answer:

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)abs:(NSDecimalNumber *)num {
    if [myNumber compare:[NSDecimalNumber zero]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        // Number is negative. Multiply by -1
        NSDecimalNumber *negativeOne = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1
                                                                    exponent:0
                                                                  isNegative:YES];
        return [num decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:negativeOne];
    } else {
        return num;
    }
}
```

And here is a version suitable to be used as a category on NSDecimalNumber:

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)abs {
    if ([self compare:[NSDecimalNumber zero]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        // Number is negative. Multiply by -1
        NSDecimalNumber *negativeOne = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1
                                                                         exponent:0
                                                                       isNegative:YES];
        return [self decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:negativeOne];
    } else {
        return self;
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the pointer, and thanks for the instance implementation!

Answer (score 6):

If you do not want to multiply it, zero subtracting the value will do the trick.

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)abs:(NSDecimalNumber *)num {
    if ([num compare:[NSDecimalNumber zero]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        // negative value
        return [[NSDecimalNumber zero] decimalNumberBySubtracting:num];
    } else {
        return num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 4.0 variant:

```swift
extension NSDecimalNumber {
    func absoluteValue() -> NSDecimalNumber {
        if self.compare(NSDecimalNumber.zero) == .orderedAscending {
            let negativeValue = NSDecimalNumber(mantissa: 1, exponent: 0, isNegative: true)
            return self.multiplying(by: negativeValue)
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

usage

```swift
let sum = NSDecimalNumber(value: -123.33)

sum.absoluteValue()
```

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 5

You can use the `magnitude` property of `Decimal`:

```
extension NSDecimalNumber {
    var absValue: Self {
        .init(decimal: decimalValue.magnitude)
    }
}
```

```
let number = NSDecimalNumber(string: "-123.456")
let absNumber = number.absValue // 123.456
```