# How do I get absolute value of NSCFNumber?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a value coming from an API server. The server stores it as BigDecimal on Postgres. On the iOS side, the value is of type `__NSCFNumber`. How do I get the absolute value for `NSCFNumber`?

My primary purpose is to further convert this number to a currency.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4717090/396569 Would be helpful.

Comment: That's an internal representation of `NSNumber`. Show some code on how you get this number.

Answer (score 7):

`__NSCFNumber` is an internal class that implements the `NSNumber` interface.

If you want a `double`:

```
NSNumber *myNumber = objectFromPostgres;
double value = fabs(myNumber.doubleValue);
```

If you want a `long`:

```
NSNumber *myNumber = objectFromPostgres;
long value = labs(myNumber.longValue);
```

If you want an `int`:

```
NSNumber *myNumber = objectFromPostgres;
int value = abs(myNumber.intValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a choice on the precision, but assuming a double value, you can use this:

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:-3.14159]; // isa Class   __NSCFNumber    0x0000000101357a20
double absoluteValue = fabsl([number doubleValue]);
NSLog(@"absolute value = %f", absoluteValue);
```

Outputs:

```
absolute value = 3.141590
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked an incomplete and vague question and I'm sorry. For my sins, I'm posting my solution and maybe it can help someone.

```
NSDecimalNumberHandler *roundUp = [NSDecimalNumberHandler                                  decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundUp
                                       scale:2
                                       raiseOnExactness:NO
                                       raiseOnOverflow:NO
                                       raiseOnUnderflow:NO
                                       raiseOnDivideByZero:YES];

NSDecimalNumber *totalAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[user[@"total"] decimalValue]];
totalAmount = [[self abs:totalAmount] decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:roundUp];
```

The helper method that I got from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846254/absolute-value-abs-of-nsdecimalnumber-without-loss-of-precision).

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)abs:(NSDecimalNumber *)num {
    if ([num compare:[NSDecimalNumber zero]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        // Number is negative. Multiply by -1
        NSDecimalNumber * negativeOne = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1
                                                                          exponent:0
                                                                        isNegative:YES];
        return [num decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:negativeOne];
    } else {
        return num;
    }
}
```