# How to get an absolute value from NSDecimalNumber?

Tags: swift, decimal, absolute-value

How to get an absolute value from NSDecimalNumber? Getting absolute value from Integer is easy, but I need one from NSDecimalNumber. I have found answers from few years ago (Objective-C, for example), but I was hoping that in Swift in 2020 it is easier now.

Code from my playground:

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"

// absolute value

let intValue: Int = -5
let absoluteIntValue = abs(intValue) // works
print("\(absoluteIntValue)") // 5

let value: NSDecimalNumber = -5.234
let absoluteValue = abs(value) // doesn't work. Gives an error: Cannot convert value of type 'NSDecimalNumber' to expected argument type 'Int32'
print("\(absoluteValue)")
```

Comment: First Google result: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47571339/1187415

Comment: Or use `Decimal` instead.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR. I have found this answer. But was wondering if anything changed. And is there a way without writing an extensions (as I don't have experience with this).

Comment: As @Joakim said: Use `Decimal` and its `magnitude` property.

Comment: Thank you, @JoakimDanielson. How would I do that? Also, I am using NSDecimalNumber, because I read I should use it when working with currencies. Can I use Decimal type instead? I will save those Decimals to Core Data.

Comment: Decimal works fluently with CoreData, you can set your entity attributes to be of that type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `NSDecimalNumber` with (native) `Decimal`. The generic `abs` function considers also the `Decimal` type

```
let value: Decimal = -5.234
let absoluteValue = abs(value) 
print(absoluteValue)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works with Decimal. But I have read that I should use NSDecimalNumber if I want to work with currencies and money data. Or is it not correct and Decimal type will do just fine?

Comment: Try it out. `Decimal` is the Swift counterpart of `NSDecimalNumber` and generally Core Data supports also Swift native types.

Comment: In fact, even attribute type in my Core Data entity is Decimal. Please give me a while to try it out with Decimal values instead of NSDecimalNumber before I'll accept your answer. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Actually, `Decimal` is the counterpart of `NSDecimal`, which is the struct under `NSDecimalNumber` but many Obj-C APIs that use `NSDecimalNumber` use `Decimal` in Swift.